# How to correct Invalid Decryption Key error

Tags: apache-superset

I installed Apache-Superset on linux based VM. I can log in to the system but there is an error when I tried to access the sample dashboards in the system.

> DB Engine Error Invalid decryption key This may be triggered by:
> Issue 1011 - Superset encountered an unexpected error.

Please advice on how to correct this error. Thank you

Comment: See answers at https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/8538